# Generic Intent method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, start-activity

I am trying to create a common method to send a destination Activity as a parameter to this method and a new Intent should be created with this destination activity.
following is the sample code i am trying to achieve.

```
fun prepareIntent(target:Activity)

{
  startActivity(this,target::class.java)

}
fun startActivityA()
{

   if(true){
   prepareIntent(A)
   }
   else
   {
     prepareIntent(B)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setClass` method of the `Intent` class can be used very well in this case I guess

```
val resultIntent =  Intent();

  if (condition) {
     resultIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), XXXX::class.java);
                startActivity(resultIntent);
  }else {
     resultIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), YYYY.class::java);
  }

startActivity(intent)// to start the activity
```